# Enable TLSv1.2 in Coldfusion

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, coldfusion

I am currently looking for a way to enable TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2, not TLSv1(.0) in the Coldfusion java jre. I am running Java 7 jre.

The admins decided that tlsv1 is no longer secure enough and since the problems/exploits with SSL2/SSL3 I am forced to use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2.

I have followed multiple suggestions such as use http.protocol=TLSv1.2 , this did not work, to SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"). However, since the calls are in coldfusion I cannot seem to find a way to do the getInstance, or setEnabledProtocols methods as I do not have access to the java backend being called by the cfobject/cfinvoke methods.

I have tried setting them to on by default through the Java control panel however it does not appear that these settings are used outside of applets.

Please let me know if there is anything I am missing. I am sure I can write a Java project to handle this if it is not possible but I would like to exhaust all possible solutions first.

Thank you

Comment: What "Java Control Panel"?

Comment: he means the standard settings CP that get's downloaded with a JDK.

Comment: yep, you got it javacpl.exe in the bin directory included with java

Comment: I have not tried it, but a brief search turned up [this article](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-allow-only-TLS-1-1-connections-to-Tomcat-6-0-server-with-https-td4995362.html) and [this thread](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-allow-only-TLS-1-1-connections-to-Tomcat-6-0-server-with-https-td4995362.html) which both mention setting the connector "SSLProtocol" property in `server.xml`, ie SSLProtocol="TLSv1.1". Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am skeptical that this will work but I will definitely give it a try. The reason is, the included tomcat bundled with Coldfusion 11 has a bug with the sslprotocols always enabling ssl3 with tls. I will let you know in the morning when I can give it a try. Thank you

Comment: Oh, that stinks. Sounds like it might not work then, but as you say, would not hurt to confirm it one way or the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. In case anyone is interested, I am running Apache Tomcat/7.0.52. These settings did not work: sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" OR sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" OR
sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" OR sslProtocols="TLSv1.2"

These setting do not appear to stay set for the entire execution of the JVM, they are most likely for the server endpoint itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace Java 7 with Java 8. Java 8 has the required protocols enabled and set to default automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this switch to your Java args in the /runtime/bin/jvm.config file (the location of this file can vary with the type of your CF install).

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Then check the out log (cfusion-out.log in runtime/logs on a standard install) for information on each handshake (outgoing) that it makes. You will likely see some clues there and be able to determine which protocol/level of TLS is reached by SSL connections from the server. This link on [diagnosing TLS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https) has some useful tidbits as well - though you will have to figure out how they translate to ColdFusion.

Note that the CPL for Java will be of no use to you here. The JVM is started with it's own config file that details what it can and cannot support. The CPL is going to set up standard INI files that are used by a java client (an application on desktop) but CF runs as a serve instance and won't use that information. I'm not even sure where it is stored :)

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to already able to determine what is happening. The problem is java7 SUPPORTS up to TLSv1.2 but only has SSL3 and TLSv1 enabled by default. These settings do not appear to be configureable through Coldfusion code when using the included functions, not cfscript. I verified that the handshake works by setting my apache server to allow only TLSv1 but the moment I remove that and only allow TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 it fails. Thank you for your reply